# SWreveal View Controller and Subview

Tags: ios, swift, addsubview, swrevealviewcontroller, tinder

i'm currently developping an app, which allow users to use the swype gesture (slide to the left if you like or right if dont), to do it, i'm using a library (which use addSubview) but , i'm also using the SWRevealViewController, to make my side menu.

The main problem is, i dont know how to  implement programmatically the gesture on my "addSubview" view.

Of course i already use the :

self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

but it doesn't work.

Thank you !

This is my two main controller :

library :

```
import UIKit

class KinderCardView: UIView {

private var isFliped: Bool = false
private var isAnimated: Bool = false

private var imageViewContent: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    return imageView
}()

private lazy var titleLabelContent: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(17)
    return label
}()

private lazy var descLabelContent: UITextView = {
    let desc = UITextView()
    desc.editable = false
    desc.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17)
    desc.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)
    desc.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    desc.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    desc.selectable = false
    return desc
}()

var imageContent: UIImage! {
    get {
        return self.imageViewContent.image
    }
    set {
        self.imageViewContent.image = newValue
    }
}

var titleContent: String! {
    get {
        return self.titleLabelContent.text
    }
    set {
        self.titleLabelContent.text = newValue
        self.titleLabelContent.frame.origin = CGPointMake(10, ((self.frame.size.height - self.frame.size.width) / 2 -
            self.titleLabelContent.frame.size.height / 2) + self.frame.size.width)
    }
}

var descContent: String! {
    get {
        return descLabelContent.text
    }
    set {
        descLabelContent.text = newValue
    }
}

var size: CGSize! {
    get {
        return self.frame.size
    }
    set {
        self.frame.size = newValue
        self.imageViewContent.frame.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.width, self.frame.width)
        self.titleLabelContent.frame.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width - 20, 30)
        self.titleLabelContent.frame.origin = CGPointMake(10, self.frame.size.width + 10)
    }
}

func flipCard() {
    if isAnimated {
        return
    }
    if isFliped == false {
        descLabelContent.frame.size = CGSizeMake(size.width - 20, size.height - 20)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.1,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.allZeros, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)
                self.imageViewContent.alpha = 0
                self.titleLabelContent.alpha = 0
                self.descLabelContent.alpha = 1
                self.isAnimated = true
            }, completion: { (anim:Bool) -> Void in
                self.isAnimated = false
        })
        isFliped = true
    }
    else {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.1,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.allZeros, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)
                self.imageViewContent.alpha = 1
                self.titleLabelContent.alpha = 1
                self.descLabelContent.alpha = 0
                self.isAnimated = true
            }, completion: { (anim:Bool) -> Void in
                self.isAnimated = false
        })
        isFliped = false
    }

}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height))
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    self.layer.borderWidth = 5
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.88, green:0.88, blue:0.88, alpha:1).CGColor
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.imageViewContent.frame.size = CGSizeMake(size.width, size.width)
    self.addSubview(self.imageViewContent)

    self.titleLabelContent.frame.size = CGSizeMake(size.width - 20, 30)
    self.titleLabelContent.frame.origin = CGPointMake(10, size.width + 10)
    self.addSubview(self.titleLabelContent)

    descLabelContent.alpha = 0
    descLabelContent.frame.size = CGSizeMake(size.width - 20, size.height - 20)
    descLabelContent.frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 10)
    self.addSubview(descLabelContent)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

And the view which load my library :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class swipe : UIViewController, KinderDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var loading: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var loadinglab: UILabel!

var data: Array<KinderModelCard>! = Array()
let controller = KinderViewController()
var backnetwork: NSInteger!

var jsonData: NSDictionary!

//var mutable_pages = NSMutableArray()
var recherche = String()
var category = String()
var zipCode = String()
var price = String()


override func viewDidLoad() {

    //loadingimage.hidden = false
    loading.hidden = false
    loadinglab.hidden = false

    //initialisation de la variable backnetwork
    self.backnetwork = 0



}


func acceptCard(card: KinderModelCard?) {

}

func cancelCard(card: KinderModelCard?) {

}



func fetchData(int: Int, completion: (()->())?) {


    loading.hidden = false
    loadinglab.hidden = false

    NSLog("recherche=%@&categorie=%@&code postal=%@&prix=%@", recherche , category, zipCode, price)



    //Data que l'on envoie en post dans le webservice
    var post:NSString = "recherche=\(recherche)&category=\(category)&zipCode=\(zipCode)&price=\(price)"

    //On remplace les espace par du vide pour la recherche
    var deletespace = post.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: NSMakeRange(0, post.length))

    NSLog("Requete: %@",deletespace);



    var url:NSURL = NSURL(string:"http://jdl-barreme-orange.dyndns.org/WEBSERVICE/controllers/controller.objects.php?method=findObject")!


    var postData:NSData = deletespace.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

    var postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

    NSLog("PostData: %@",postLength);

    var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = postData
    request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


    var reponseError: NSError?
    var response: NSURLResponse?

    var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&reponseError)





    if ( urlData != nil ) {

        NSLog("urlData: %ld", urlData!);

        let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!;

        NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

        if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
        {



            var responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

            //On remplace les backslashe par du vide pour l'url de l'image
            var responsestring = responseData.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: NSMakeRange(0, responseData.length))

            NSLog("Response ==> %@", responsestring);

            var error: NSError?


                            //[jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];

            let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as! NSDictionary


            let success:NSInteger = jsonData.valueForKey("success") as! NSInteger



            //[jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];

            NSLog("Success: %ld", success);

            if(success == 1)
            {


                if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: nil, error: nil) as? [String:AnyObject] {
                    for (_, value) in json {
                        if let dict = value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                            let repo = Repository(jsonData: dict)
                            repos.append(repo)
                        }
                    }
                }




                NSLog("Recherche OK");


                loading.hidden = true
                loadinglab.hidden = true

                let newCard = Model()

                let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

                for repo in repos {
                    //NSLog("title: %@", repo.title!)
                    println(repo.idobjet)
                    println(repo.title)
                    println(repo.price)
                    println(repo.description)
                    println(repo.added)
                    println(repo.userid)
                    println(repo.user_name)
                    println(repo.user_zipCode)
                    println(repo.category_id)
                    println(repo.category_label)
                    println(repo.subcategory_id)
                    println(repo.subcategory_label)
                    println(repo.picture_url)

                }

                //Construct the imgUrl to get an image URL for the pages
                let urlString: NSString =  repos.picture_url!
                if let url = NSURL(string: urlString as String) {
                    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                        newCard.image = UIImage(data: data)!

                        newCard.content = appDelegate.titreApp

                        NSLog("le titre est %@", appDelegate.titreApp)

                        newCard.desc = appDelegate.priceApp
                        self.data.append(newCard)
                        NSLog("fetch new data")

                        }
                    }
                }



            else {


                loading.hidden = true
                loadinglab.hidden = true
                //on définit backnetwork à 2 pour reloadCard
                self.backnetwork = 2

                var error_msg:NSString

                //on récupére le message dans le php, avec le champ du JSON "message" et on l'affiche
                if jsonData["message"] as? NSString != nil {
                    error_msg = jsonData["message"] as! NSString
                } else {
                    error_msg = "Erreur inconnue"
                }
                var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                alertView.title = "Recherche échouée"
                alertView.message = error_msg as String
                alertView.delegate = self
                alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                alertView.show()

                //On appel la fonction reloadCard qui vas lire 2 à backnetwork et dismiss
                reloadCard()

                return
            }

        }
        else {
            completion!()


            loading.hidden = true
            loadinglab.hidden = true

            var error_msg:NSString

            //on récupére le message dans le php, avec le champ du JSON "message" et on l'affiche
            if jsonData["message"] as? NSString != nil {
                error_msg = jsonData["message"] as! NSString
            } else {
                error_msg = "Erreur inconnue"
            }
            var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
            alertView.title = "Recherche échouée"
            alertView.message = error_msg as String
            alertView.delegate = self
            alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
            alertView.show()

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            return
        }
    }
    else {

        completion!()
        //si UrlData est nil, j'incrémente ma variable backnetwork à 1 pour reloadCard
        self.backnetwork = 1
        NSLog("backnetwork DATA : %i", backnetwork)


        loading.hidden = true
        loadinglab.hidden = true

        return

    }


    if self.data.count == 5 {
        completion!()
        return
    }
    else {

        self.fetchData(0, completion: completion)
    }

}


func signalReload() {
    println("call signal")
    data.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    self.fetchData(0, completion: { () -> () in
        self.controller.reloadData()

    })


    println("end signl")

}

func reloadCard() -> [KinderModelCard]? {
    NSLog("reload data")

    //Si backnetwork =1 udlData est nil, donc impossible de joindre le serveur, check de la connexion
    if backnetwork == 1 {
        NSLog("backnetwork reload : %i", backnetwork)
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
        alertView.title = "Recherche échouée"
        alertView.message = "Vérifiez votre connexion"
        alertView.delegate = self
        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alertView.show()

    }
        //Si backnetwork =2 la recherche n'est pas bonne, provient de
    else if backnetwork == 2 {
        NSLog("backnetwork reload : %i", backnetwork)
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }


    return data

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    //si backnetwork est égale à 1 alors je dismiss
    if backnetwork == 1 {
        NSLog("backnetwork viewdid : %i", backnetwork)
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


    }

    else {
        fetchData(0, completion: { () -> () in
            self.controller.delegate = self
            self.presentViewController(self.controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
    }

}




}
```

Thank you for reading my post.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the pan gesture? The pan gesture in the SWRevealViewController is to pan and reveal the menu I guess, so not really clear as to whether your question is linked to SWRevealViewController. Please provide a little more detail.

Comment: sorry to be late, yes , that's what i want to do, i want to allow users to use the side menu, provided by SWRevealViewController, into my subview

Comment: Your question and your comment is not clear. I suggest you revise your question and focus the code more around what you need. Do you want to add pan gesture to your view controllers to be able to open the side menu?

Comment: thanks for your help but i dont know how to be clearer ! i have 2 views (Swype.swift and card.swift). Card.swift is a library which create some card like tinder. When i call Card.swift in Swype.swift, that create a SubView with the cards. I just want to be able to link this subview, with SWRevealViewController.

Comment: You do not link SWRevealViewController with sub views as far as I know. It is used with view controllers to show a sliding menu drawer sort of an effect. I suggest you go through the examples and based on what you want, SWRevealViewController may not be exactly what you need.

Comment: ok, thnak you for your help !